# Convex function that has a finite limit at infinity

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Can someone give me an example for a convex function that has a finit limit at infinity ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about $f(x)=0$ for all $x$?

If that doesn't suit your fancy (because it isn't STRICTLY convex), how about $f(x)=e^{-x}$?